# blog post image slideshow

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

What I've got in my mind is that there is a blog section on my Django website. there are posts in this blog section. every post has a main photo. when you click on the main photo and post summary you can see more about that post. in the post details, there is a photo slide show which shows a couple of photos from the database. I defined my model like this:

model.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_images/', default='blog_images/default.jpg')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title


class Images(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_images/', default='blog_images/default.jpg')
```

and of course, we have admin site settings.

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post, Images


class ImagesAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Images


@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ImagesAdmin]
    list_display = ('title',)


admin.site.register(Images)
```

at last, we have views!

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from blog.models import Post, Images

def blog_single(request, **kwargs):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(status=1)
    if pid := kwargs.get('pid'):
        post = posts.get(id=pid)
        images = Images.objects.filter(post__id=post.id)
    context = {'post':post, 'images':images}
    return render(request, 'blog/blog-single.html', context)
```

The problem is that I cannot find a way to use the images in my template. My template:

```
{% load static %}
{% for img in images %}
    <div class="swiper-slide">
    <img src="{{img.url}}" alt="">
    </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: In what way are you not able to use them? What error/unwanted behaviour is it that you're getting? (Add this information to your question)

Comment: There is no error, pictures just won't show up when I run the code!

Comment: On a closer look, it looks like you are trying to get the url from the wrong property perhaps? In your template you are looping through your `Images` queryset and accessing the property `url` on each of them, but your `Images` model doesn't seem to have a `url` property, just two properties called `post` and `images`. So perhaps that's where you will find your mistake?

Comment: so what should I do?

Comment: Since you don't have a `url` field on your model, I'm going to guess that you meant to access the `url` property on your `images` field. So, in your template, try replacing `img.url` with `img.images.url` and see if that helps.

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks a lot :) I was struggling for a while with this...